How to compile and run a C script in MSYS2
beginner programmer here, I am trying a rudimentary approach, where I write some c code in a text editor (notepad++) and wish to compile it using gcc. The way to do this I found would be to install msys2 (I don't fully understand what it is, but I think it is just a package with some tools, including gcc). Then I did
pacman -S base-devel gcc vim cmake

Which I think installs gcc and some other stuff. I ran gcc:
gcc -o test.exe test.c

This gave me the exe file, but now I'm not sure how to run it. Opening it in windows cmd, says I am missing a dll file. Whereas running it in MSYS2, gives no output or any errors, but nothing happens. For reference, this is the code I am compiling:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    float a, b, c, sum;
    printf("Input three floats: ");
    scanf("%f%f%f", &a, &b, &c);
    printf("a = %f, b = %f, c = %f\n", a, b, c);
    sum = a + b + c;
    printf("The sum is: %f", sum);
    return 0;
}

This is the error I get when I run through cmd:

Tried running the exe, expected a prompt and text output, but nothing happened.

This program immediately exists after printing the values, try to open a shell (Command Prompt or Power Shell) in the location where your exe file is and then open that exe from command line interface (<exe_file_name>.exe if u use CMD)

Otherwise try to add a this line of code immediately before return line: system("pause"); this will halt the execution of code untill you press anything on keyboard. Recompile the program and try to run it.

Maybe try https://winlibs.com/ instead of msys? Or even Microsoft's own compiler?? https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/

I added a picture of the error I get when I ran the executable through cmd. Which program does it mean to reinstall, MSYS2 itself?

Also, MSYS2 is a toolchain, You can also use other toolchains, I suggest you using LLVM-Clang as Clang is optimised to compile code fast and has GNU like syntax. Alternatively you can also build your own toolchain but that's too advanced for beginners, won't recommend you that.

The error suggests that the program is looking for msys-2. 0.dll file, may I know what is your current environment setup and how are you compiling the program?

I added manually to my PATH variable the path to the msys2 folder. (not sure if I should put a more specific path to some bin folder.) I am compiling a text file in a separate directory by doing cd "that folder" and then running the gcc command in the post.

Once you have your compiling issue sorted replace printf("%sum", &sum); with printf("sum : %.2f\n", sum);

Also, I just found the dll under msys2\usr\bin. So maybe my PATH variable should point to that bin folder? Also I can only edit user variables on this PC, could that be an issue?

Okay, yes, after changing my user path variable to point to ...\msys2\usr\bin. The executable runs in cmd. However I still do not understand why it doesn't produce an output in the msys2 shell. Isn't it supposed to emulate a unix-based terminal, where running test.exe should also run the executable?

Note that MSYS2 ships several different builds of GCC, and you're using a cygwin-based one right now.

@LakshyaK2011 how could the program exit immediately if it has to wait for input for the scanf call? That assumption does not match the code.

Nvm, my bad, didn't realise that there was a scanf call too.

@LakshyaK2011 "MSYS2 is a toolchain, You can also use other toolchains" MSYS2 isn't a single toolchain, it offers several different ones, including a clang-based one.

Isn't Clang backed by LLVM? So isn't Clang over LLVM better than CLang over MSYS2?

The compiling error was due to my PATH environment variable not pointing to the specific location where gcc.exe is.
The other issue where no output was shown in MSYS2 shell was because instead of just typing the name like in cmd, I should have done:
./test


Isn't that powershell syntax, if you do without ./ In CMD, it would do the same.
